# PANDAS: Trim multiple data frames

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas

I want to remove rows from several data frames so that they are all length n.  When I tried to use a -for- loop, the changes would not persist through the rest of the script.

```
n = 50
groups = [df1, df2, df3]
for dataset in groups:
    dataset = dataset[:n]
```

Redefining names individually (e.g., df1 = df1[:n] ), works, but what are some alternate ways?  (Either through python or pandas)

More importantly, why does the -for- loop not work here?

pandas == 0.10.1 
python == 2.7.3

Comment: I would like to change df1, df2 and df3, not the list "groups", per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slight python mis-understanding, rather than to do with pandas specific one. :)

You're re-assigning the variable used in the iteration and not changing it in the list:

```
In [1]: L = [1, 2, 3]

In [2]: for i in L:
            i = i + 1

In [3]: L
Out[3]: [1, 2, 3]
```

You want to actually change the list:

```
In [4]: for i in range(len(L)):
            L[i] = L[i] + 1

In [5]: L
Out[5]: [2, 3, 4]
```

Or perhaps in a nicer syntax is to use `enumerate`:

```
In [6]: for i, x in enumerate(L):
            L[i] = x + 1     

In [7]: L
Out[7]: [3, 4, 5]
```

That is:

```
for i, dataset in enumerate(groups):
    groups[i] = dataset[:n]
```

Comment: I tested this with numpy arrays.  It changed the arrays in the list without changing the underlying arrays, which is what I want to do.

Comment: @beets Is doing `df1, df2, df3 = groups` good enough for you? If you have many more variables, or a dynamic number, then consider storing them only in the list (or dictionary).

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 50
groups = [df1, df2, df3]
groups = [df.head(n) for df in groups]
```

---

In Python, you can think of variable names as pointing to objects.
The statement

```
groups = [df1, df2, df3]
```

makes the variable name, `groups`, point to a list object, which contains 3 other objects.

The `for-loop`:

```
for dataset in groups:
```

creates a new variable name, `dataset`, which *also* points to the objects inside `groups`, one at a time as Python iterates through the loop.

The assignment

```
dataset = dataset[:n]
```

**redirects** the variable name `dataset` to point to a new object, `dataset[:n]`. But this assignment does not affect `groups`. That variable name is still pointing to the `list` object, which contains the original DataFrames.

To affect `groups`, you need to either assign a new value for `groups` with as assignment statement, such as

```
groups = ...
```

or assign a new value for one of the elements in the list:

```
groups[i] = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates (and discards) a new variable `dataset` in the for-loop.

Try this:

```
n = 50
groups = [df1, df2, df3]
for dataset in groups:
    dataset[:] = dataset[:n]
```

Comment: I tested this with two 5x1 arrays with n=2.  I got the error message, "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5) (2)"